# 'Subquery' object has no attribute 'scalar_subquery' (when trying to address SAWarning about 'scalar_subquery')

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a subquery defined as

```
subqueryPrimaryApproverIc1 = db_session.query(ParticipatingIcT.id).filter(
      (ParticipatingIcT.id == agreement.participating_ic_id),                                    
      (ParticipatingIcT.ic_nihsac == func.substr(approver.nihsac, 1, 3))
).subquery()
```

and I was using it in my main Select as

```
...
func.exists(subquerySecondApproverIc1)
...
```

I got the following SAWarning:

```
SAWarning: implicitly coercing SELECT object to scalar subquery; please use the .scalar_subquery() method to produce a scalar subquery.
```

so I changed the call to

```
func.exists(subquerySecondApproverIc1.scalar_subquery()),
```

and now the error is

```
'Subquery' object has no attribute 'scalar_subquery'
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling scalar_subquery() on the result of subquery.

You should have the original declaration be

```
subqueryPrimaryApproverIc1 = db_session.query(ParticipatingIcT.id).filter(
      (ParticipatingIcT.id == agreement.participating_ic_id),                                    
      (ParticipatingIcT.ic_nihsac == func.substr(approver.nihsac, 1, 3))
).scalar_subquery()
```